# How to add a periodic timer callback in a linux kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, interrupt

I'm working on a Linux kernel module that registers a callback for interrupts that come from a custom-made board and puts the received data in a queue behind a char device interface to be processed by an application. This module needs to constantly monitor and measure the interrupts and data that comes from the board even if no interrupt comes from the board, so it has another callback that triggers according to time.

Current implementation uses RTC interrupt as a constant timer source. I disable kernel RTC drivers (`CONFIG_RTC_DRV_CMOS`) and request for IRQ 8 and hook the timer callback as RTC interrupt handler. Interrupts are generated every second from RTC chip.

The problem is we have to lose some of Linux' ability to manage time in this way, because only one of `rtc-cmos` or the board module can be loaded at once (and obviously we've chosen the board module).

Linux kernel is from `linux-source` package that comes with Debian 7.2 stable, which is at version `3.2+46`. Target architecture is i386 PC.

I'm not a kernel developer and so don't have a big picture on kernel module development, but I'm trying to find my way and these are nearest thing to solution that come to my mind:

- Somehow share the IRQ 8 between both modules (maybe like `request_irq(8, rtc_handler, IRQF_SHARED, rtc_handler)`?) or chainload IRQ handlers.
- Finding another way to hook a handler from a kernel module to RTC interrupt, rather than registering for IRQ 8.
- Finding another source of 1-second timer events that can be used from within a kernel module, maybe there is a standard kernel API for that, I don't know.

I suppose there might be a simple and standard way to do this and I would be glad if anyone would comment on either of these solutions or suggest others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> maybe there is a standard kernel API for that

Of course there is.  Needing a timer in a kernel module is probably not unusual.

I don't know much about the API, but I do know it exists.  If you are going to write a kernel module *properly*, you should get a book or something; there are several.<sup>1</sup>  Anyway, one traditional method would be:

```
#include <linux/timer.h>

schedule_timeout(jiffies);
```

That's a passive sleep. Jiffies are a unit based on a 250 HZ tick within the processor, although this may be configurable.   That header has various other functions, here's [a brief discussion](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-timers-list/) involving the 2.6 kernel, but I would assume 3.x must still be compatible with this, since a lot of the source, including drivers, is older than that.  There's an easy way to find out of course.

Jiffies is probably fine if you want a delay of a second.  Granularity for passive sleeps on the millisecond level is a problem with a regular kernel because of scheduler latency, but there is a nanosecond granularity API too in [ktime.h](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/ktime.h) (that link is from a 2.6 kernel again, but the file is still dated 2005 in the 3.11 source, so has not changed).  Keep in mind that linux also has userspace timers with nanosecond granularity, but this does not mean they will actually work for timing things on that level because of scheduler latency (and presumably this is also true for passive timers in kernel space).

You can access the RTC instead of using processor/kernel ticks, but there are some disadvantages:

- Not all systems actually have one.
- Implies busy looping.

And no real advantages.  AFAIK the RTC *is not* considered more accurate than processor ticks.

<sup>1</sup> Another resource you would be wise to make use of is the [Linux Kernel Mailing List](http://www.tux.org/lkml/) (LKML), which is where the devs are, and they do answer questions.  Be warned the list has a volume into the hundreds of messages per day.

Comment: Thanks for great answer, I'll rewrite and test the module using kernel timer and inform you of results.